# I can't custom font on reagent's react native with expo?

Tags: react-native, fonts, clojurescript, expo, reagent

My project is clojureScript reagent's react native with expo, and I need to custom the font. I already read expo's doc about how to custom font and tried to follow the instruction in the ClojureScript way.

(expo's custom font instruction 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts)

1. async loading font, this is loading async function

   ```
   (defn load-font-async
    [name url]
    (.call (aget Font "loadAsync")
      Font
      (js-obj "Kanit" url)))
   ```
2. called the loading async function before rendered.

   ```
   (->
    (expo/load-font-async "Kanit" (js/require "./assets/fonts/Kanit/Kanit-Regular.ttf"))
    (.then (fn [] (.registerComponent app-registry "main" #(r/reactify-component app-root))))))
   ```

   ps. It not good to hold the all app just for font loading, but I just need to ensure that font is already loaded. ( I need refactor)
3. I put font family style to text component

   ```
   [text {:style {:font-family "Kanit"}} "test"]
   ```

but text component can't find font family "Kanit" that I already declare and loading. the error was

```
 Unrecognized font family 'Kanit'
```

I'm blank for now, What wrong with this solution ?

ps. tell me if you need more information, thanks for all response :)

**UPDATED** : from Chris Callwait's recommend I moved `expo/load-font-async` in to app-root and dispatch for tell text component only attach font family on the font is loaded. like this

```
(defn app-root []
  (let [ ... ]
  (expo/load-font-async [{"Kanit" (js/require "./assets/fonts/Kanit/Kanit-Regular.ttf")}]
    (rf/dispatch [:app/set-font-loaded true]))
  (r/create-class {:reagent-render ..... }))))
```

and it still has the same error :( .

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution, it uses Promise.All for call Font.loadAsync and that loads multiple fonts at once.

```
(defn- cache-fonts [fonts]
  (for [font fonts]
    (when font
      (.loadAsync Font font))))

(defn- cast-as-array [coll]
  (if (or (array? coll)
          (not (reduceable? coll)))
    coll
    (into-array coll)))

(defn all [coll]
  (.all js/Promise (cast-as-array coll)))

(defn load-fonts [fonts cb]
  (->
    (all (cache-fonts (clj->js fonts)))
    (.then (fn [resp]
             (if cb (cb))))
    (.catch (fn [err]
              (println "Loading font failed: " (aget err "message"))))))


(load-fonts [{"Kanit" (js/require "./assets/fonts/Kanit/Kanit-Regular.ttf")}]
            (println "Font success loaded"))
```

My init:

```
(defn app-root []
  (let [...]
    (load-fonts ...)
    (fn []
      ...)))

(defn init []
  (.registerComponent app-registry "main" #(r/reactify-component app-root)))
```

Comment: thanks for reponse Chris, I still have the same error. could you guide me about the place to call "load-fonts" ? for now, I called it before the first component on app is rendered. can you give me an example.

Comment: I call load fonts inside main component. I've edited the example

Comment: it's same as me, but I still got the error  `Unrecognized font family 'Kanit'`.

Comment: Should I require all font in the font package (eg. Kanit-Lite, ...) ? for now, I require only the regular font. Is it related to the problem ?

Comment: I think need to move expo/load-font-async inside app-root. In your example you use threading and it doesn't add in registerComponent.  Single font should works.

Comment: I updated the question to show you how I follow your suggestion. Is that correct?

Comment: It looks correctly, sometimes I have an issue with loading new assets and I just reloading lein figwheel

Comment: thanks for the reply, I reloaded many times, but it still has the same problem. I tried to log to check is the font loaded before called text component or not, and the result was correct.